# Strategies on speeding up queries on SQL Server with large amounts of data

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that holds large amounts of data. It's expected that data will grow very fast to millions of rows within short periods. Indexed views are used to read data.

Doing queries on some views takes about 35-40 seconds. We'll work on fine-tuning queries but there is no guarantee that this is the only option. I think with vast amount of records, execution time will not be acceptable.

Now I am reflecting on what else could be done.

For example there are 2 time periods that are most expected to be used: 1 year back from current date and last 24 hours.

What's your opinions on trying to do like this?

Create 3 databases, `db_A` for today records, `db_B` for yesterday minus 365, and an archive `db_C` - everything that is older than a year. Thus we are probably facing to write a service to do copying to another db and deleting from the first one.

Then maybe linked servers could be used or some API written to determine which database(s) to query. Of course even yearly period will contain vast amount of records, but this is still better. Insertion/updating in `db_A` will be faster and there is a good chance that many queries will hit `db_A`.

Are there some literate solutions for such scenarios. Will hosting databases at physically different locations will improve performance (due to parallel execution).

Professional advice is appreciated.

Comment: No. Do not create multiple databases, that will just give you headaches. You can instead create a partitioned table. This makes the 'partitioning' invisible to the user. I'm suprised that you have implemented indexed views but not considered partitioned tables?

Comment: I haven't implemented them.  But I now have to optimize it.  May be an idea I had about multiple db is a bit complicated, but i think some archiving can be done.

Comment: Partitioned tables basically do what you're suggesting - split the data into possibly different datafiles, but it is transparent to the user.